# Throw exception and NOT terminate program in java

Tags: java, exception

So I have a program that I want to check if a set of cords are inside a gameboard, and if they are not, to throw an error, but continue with the program. Here is the code used (I'm not worried about class/package names):

```
package routines;

import java.util.Random;

import game.GameBoard;
import game.Player;

public class MovePlayer extends Routine {
final protected int destX;
final protected int destY;

public MovePlayer(int destX, int destY, GameBoard board) {
    super();
    if(destY > board.getHeight() || destX > board.getWidth()) {
        fail();
        throw new RuntimeException(">>> Error while creating routine, one or more coords are outside of the game board");
    } else {
        this.destX = destX;
        this.destY = destY;
    }
}
```

And here is a link to the super class (a lot of code, not sure if I should put all of it in here) [Super class SRC](http://pastebin.com/3iAh9sGY)

EDIT: Not sure if this will fix what I was wanting, but all I did was remove the `final` keyword from the variables

EDIT #2: So I finally figured what I was doing wrong. 1) the variables were marked as final. 2) It was some of my other code that was causing this to happen **facepalm** All of my code has been pushed to a new Git repository, so if you should so choose, you can look at what I did here: [VI-Arena Git repository](https://github.com/AXIUM1998/VI-Arena)

Comment: Please check how to use [`try` block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html).

Comment: The exception will be thrown and must be catched by the class that attempted to create the `MovePlayer` object. In that class, you should use a `try ... catch` block, as mentioned by Luiggi

Comment: Exceptions are your friend. You can use them to escape the block of code you are in to get up the stack to a place where you can handle it. In cases like your example here, I recommend you make a custom Exception type, so you don't go catching exceptions you didn't mean to

Comment: I will definitely look into creating my own exceptions as I see that helping tremendously in the rest of this project

Comment: No need for a custom exception. `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument. That sounds like exactly the case here. The constructor was passed an inappropriate destX or destY.

Comment: Someone posted an answer that demonstrates how to catch an exception so that the program may continue executing. What part of your question remains unanswered?

Comment: I don't know what you did, but final variables are not causing your issue. You can throw an exception without initializing a final variables and everything will be just fine. I posted some code as an answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what and how to do what I was needing. What I needed to stop the creation of the routine object if conditions were met, and that was done by throwing an error. That was being done, but I was mistakenly setting the variables INSIDE the `try...catch` block. So, if the conditions are not satisfied, it fails and stops, if they are satisfied, it creates the object and sets the variables OUTSIDE of the `try...catch` block, which works. My new code is as follows:

```
package routines;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import game.*;

public class MovePlayer extends Routine {

    private final int destX;
    private final int destY;
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public MovePlayer(int destX, int destY, GameBoard board) throws IOException {
        super();
        try {
            if (destY > board.getHeight() || destX > board.getWidth()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(">>> Error while creating routine, one or more coords are outside of the game board");
            } else {
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            fail();
        System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    this.destX = destX;
    this.destY = destY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the

```
try{

}
catch(Exception){

}
finally{

}
```

block you can handle exceptions instead of letting them crash your program!

Your code comes in the try block, and in the catch block you can handle the Exception which is being thrown from the executing code in the try-block.

The finally block is used to close or finalize used resources in order to not leave them opened. Not doing that might - ironically - throw you even more exceptions.

I would definitely look up on that, it's a very commonly used part of modern languages!

Comment: Should probably mention the `finally` statement as well. A very common error sense is to open `FileWriter` and never close it, because of an `exception`.

Comment: @Emz indeed, I added that.

Comment: @mastah, we can, but then we also have to close it in the `try` block.

Comment: @mastah You could, but then if the block of code *doesn't* throw an exception, your stream would remain open.

Comment: Upon catching the error, the variables destX and destY are not set, but need to as they are final

Comment: oh now i get it, like some1 use it to avoid code duplication (for mostly i was closing streams both in try and catch)

Comment: BTW, it would be better to use a try-with-resources. That will close the stream after everything is done, error or no error

Comment: You really need to understand try-catch-finally before you move on to try-with-resources, because 1) not all resources you encounter will implement the Disposable interface (or whatever it's called in Java), and 2) not all languages have that construct.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if I could do it by having the super class implement closable...